# Delete old cookies on select option change

Tags: jquery, jquery-cookie

I have a select option and I want to save selected values in every click. This is my script

```
// on change deletes bill_client_id old values and set the new values
jQuery("#bill_client_id").change(function() {   
    jQuery.cookie('bill_client_id"', '', { expires: -1 });
    jQuery.cookie('bill_client_id', jQuery("#bill_client_id").val());
    alert(jQuery.cookie("bill_client_id"));
})

// on document ready Select options by values
for(var i = 0 ; i < jQuery.cookie('bill_client_id').length; i++) {              
    jQuery("#bill_client_id option[value='"+jQuery.cookie('bill_client_id')[i]+"']").attr('selected', 'selected');
}
```

The problem is `bill_client_id` is saved 2 times (I can see them in Firebug) and on document ready I got only the old `bill_client_id`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe its because your cookie names don't match?

```
jQuery.cookie('bill_client_id"', '', { expires: -1 });
```

Should be:

```
jQuery.cookie('bill_client_id', '', { expires: -1 });
```

Comment: For something like this where you use the same identifier in a number of places I'd be tempted to define it in a common place to minimise risk of typos like this. That also makes it flexible if you need to alter the name easily because of a clash later.

Comment: @MohamedOmezzine Can you explain whats not working? This should have solved your issue of having two cookies being set. If you have another question as to why its not working it would be recommended to start another question.

Comment: I chnaged 'bill_client_id"' to 'bill_client_id'  and i still have  tow cookies called bill_client_id :/

Comment: @MohamedOmezzine Did you clear your cache/cookies after updating the code?